# ember.js Reset route variable when changed model

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am creating some CRUD Ember.js 2.1.0 / Ember-data 2.1.0 with Ruby on Rails 5.

I have `contacts` and `contacts/show` route

When I click a item in list, current route Change to `contacts/show` route.

and `contacts/show` has `isEdit` variable for inline editing.
but I expect `isEdit` will be reset when I click another item.

check my console when beforeModel, afterModel and setupController, all of my test spit `false` out. but it is not related with `isEdit` and template.

I click edit button isEdit is changed `true`

```
<p>
{{#if isEdit}}
<button {{action "save"}}>SAVE</button>
<button {{action "cancel"}}>CANCEL</button>
{{else}}
<button {{action "edit"}}>EDIT</button>
{{/if}}
</p>
```

my contacts/show template

```
        save: function() {
        var controller = this.controller;
        var item = controller.get('model');
        if(!item.get('title') || item.get('title') === '') {
            item.rollbackAttributes();
            controller.set('isEdit', false);
        } else {            
            item.save();
            controller.set('isEdit', false);            
        }
    },
```

it works well, but I can't get 'false' on loaded new model

How I set isEdit `false` when I change same route and different model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to do this in my experience is when entering the route, setting the value in the `setupController` hook. This wil ensure that every time you navigate to it `isEdit` will be set to `false`.

Here's an example of the code:

`app/routes/contacts/show.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { set } = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller) {
    set(controller, 'isEdit', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried `this.set(controller,'isEdit', false);` change this to Ember it works well